# Airtable Iframe autoscroll on load

Tags: html, css, iframe, autoscroll, airtable

I have a simple webpage that has a navigation bar along the top and it loads an Iframe from Airtable, my issue is whenever the page loads it does load and start at the top, it seems to scroll down slightly and be showing the first question in my Iframe form. I am wanting it to just load normally as the title of the form is cut off. I want the page to load at the top displaying the navigation bar also.

```
<body>  
    <nav class="navbar bg-dark border-bottom border-body" data-bs-theme="dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
      <img src="Images/Diageo St James gate Logo.png" alt="Diageo" width="220" height="55">
    </a>
</nav>
    
    <script src="https://static.airtable.com/js/embed/embed_snippet_v1.js"></script><iframe class="airtable-embed airtable-dynamic-height" src="https://airtable.com/embed/app9yPQe5Y22gwDSv/shrRdy6KOGHgMO6Rs?backgroundColor=blue" width="100%" height="0.00" style="background: transparent; border: 1px solid #ccc;"></iframe>
         
    <footer class="footer">
    <div class="container">
      <span style="color: white">© Copyright: Helix-2023</span>
    </div>
        <img src="Images/Helix Interface_GREY.png" alt="Helix">
        </footer>
</body>
```

That's pretty much the entire page of html except from scripts for bootstrap.
I read a thing where to change the iframe height but it didn't fix my issue and also seen a script about loading and it didn't change anything.

Any help would be greatly apprecaited.
Thanks